# Troubleshooting Grails merged configuration during application startup

Tags: grails, deployment, groovy, configuration, diagnostics

Suppose I have a Grails application named `myCoolApp`.

Furthermore, suppose I have defined some basic properties in `grails-app/conf/Config.groovy` and `grails-app/conf/DataSource.groovy` under the `test` and `production` profiles.

`Config.groovy` is set to merge with the following `.groovy` external configuration file, **if found at all**:

```
grails.config.locations = ["file:${userHome}/.grails/${appName}-config.groovy"]
```

Finally, I have also defined, inside an external testing server, such a file, under a local *NIX user path:

```
/home/appServerTestUser/.grails/myCoolApp-config.groovy
```

Sadly, I find that for some reason, the external `.groovy` file's properties are not being merged when a Tomcat instance starts up.

- What options do I have to make Grails tell me: "Oh, yes, I found your external config file at: `/home/appServerTestUser/.grails/myCoolApp-config.groovy`" and these are the properties I merged into `Config.groovy`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File-based paths don't make much sense in a deployed app. It could work when deploying on your dev machine for testing, but will likely fail on any other machine. And it'll probably fail locally even if configured with the correct path since the process will like run as a different low-priviledge user.

You can use absolute paths, e.g. `/etc/myapp/path/to/file`, but this tends to couple deployment to filesystem structure, so if you develop in Windows and deploy on Linux it'd be tricky to get them both working.

So the best bet for Tomcat deployment is to use the classpath syntax. You can specify multiple files and it will load all that it finds, so I usually have one entry for local dev and one for the deployed app:

```
grails.config.locations = [
   "classpath:${appName}-config.groovy",
   "file:./${appName}-config.groovy"
]
```

I delete the entries for .properties files because Groovy syntax is so much more flexible, but use them if you like. I also keep the dev files in the project root (and exclude from source control).

So when deploying, name the file correctly (different apps will have different files, so no clashing there) and put them in Tomcat's lib directory. This is in the classpath, and so the `classpath:` entry will see it.

Comment: Alright. Class path approach it is then. Thanks! :)